# How to update the array and its object in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array which collects objects. 
I want to implement insert operataion function which gets some path array "idsListPath" and the new object which we want to insert "itemToInsert".

EXAMPLE:

```
function InsertIntoDataSet(idsListPath, itemToInsert)
//idsListPath: the path where i want to add "itemToInsert" object
{
    //How do i push the itemToInsert in correct path?
}
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
var idsListPath = ["1", "3", "44"];
var itemToInsert = { id: "111", node: [] };
var dataSet = [{
    id: "1", node: [
        {
            id: "98",
            node: []
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            node: [{
                id: "44",
                node: [] //TARGET LOCATION TO PUSH THE NEW ITEM
            }]
        }]
},
{
    id: "3",
    node: []
},
{
    id: "44",
    node: []
}];
```

As in sample our path is "1", "3", "44"...

So new object item should insert into dataSet of the object having id "1" > Its child node having id "3" > its child node having id "44" > under node [] i want to push the new object item.

How can i achieve this? Even if "idsListPath" array have single value that function should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation of *InsertIntoDataSet* that achieves what you need:

```
function InsertIntoDataSet(idsListPath, itemToInsert)
{
    var currentNode = dataSet;

    for(var idx in idsListPath) {
        var id = idsListPath[idx];

        if(currentNode = findChildArrayByNodeId(currentNode, id)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    if(currentNode) {
        currentNode.push(itemToInsert);
    }
}

function findChildArrayByNodeId(nodeArray, id) {
    var node = nodeArray.filter(function(el) {
        return el.id == id;
    })[0];

    return node ? node.node : undefined;
}
```

See [live example](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/JdYRGZ).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is pass the dataset as an argument to your function and amend it there.

Since object arguments are passed by-reference in JavaScript functions, you will update the initial object (not a copy of it).

In brief it could be something like:

```
function InsertIntoDataSet(idsListPath, itemToInsert, dataSet)
{
    if (!idsListPath.length) {
        // There are no more nodes to search for; insert.
        dataSet.insert(itemToInsert);
        return true;
    } else {
        dataSet.every(function (node) {
            if (node.id == idsListPath[0]) {
                idsListPath.splice(0, 1) // Remove the first element
                return InsertIntoDataSet(isdListPath, itemToInsert, node.node) // Recurse into the current node's dataset
            }
        })
    }
}
// Maybe you 'd like also to make a clone of idsListPath in each step in order not to amend the initial object.
```

**EDIT**: Corrected my answer, as I misunderstood the question at first.

Comment: Ok thanks for quick reply. How can i push that new object in exact location?>

Comment: The [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) JavaScript function is what you need there actually.